# Translating Transactional Email Magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation

I have a magento2 store with two languages (en, es) and I would like that my customers receive their emails in the language they sign up with. (new account, forgot password, new purchase, etc).

I'm currently using crowdin module for most of my translations on the site.

I've tried translating the strings that are already in the english email template with the .csv that's in the magento2translations & no luck.

Can anyone explain me in detail how can I get the email translation done?

Comment: There is a bug with translations and email (orderconfirmation) in version 2.0. It seems there is a bugfix according to the release notes of version 2.1.0: Enabling inline translations no longer breaks order emails. ([GITHUB-4917](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4917))